# How does swifts type inference work for empty arrays?

Tags: swift, swift5

The following example illustrates the problem:

```
func f(_ a: [Int]){ print("foo") }
func f(_ a: [[Int]]){ print("bar") }
f([])
```

This does not compile with the following error:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'f'
f([])
^
note: found this candidate
func f(_ a: [Int]){ }
     ^
note: found this candidate
func f(_ a: [[Int]]){ }
```

Although this is not very nice it can be easily circumvented by helping the compiler with calls such as `f([Int]())` or `f([[Int]]())`.

However, it gets more tricky if the example above is slightly modified:

```
func f(_ a: [Int], b: Int = 0){ print("foo") }
func f(_ a: [[Int]]){ print("bar") }
f([])
f([[]])
f([Int]())
```

This example compiles without a problem, but prints (surprisingly)

```
bar
bar
foo
```

From my naive point of view I would either expected a compilation error or

```
foo
bar
foo
```

Version Note: Apple Swift version 5.0.1 (swiftlang-1001.0.82.4 clang-1001.0.46.5)

Comment: It's simple - "no parameter" takes precedence over "parameter with a default value".

Comment: Presumably it's taking the "closest match," which would be `f(:)` rather than `f(:b:)`.